Extract road contours, not just lines
I have a result of CADMAPPER plugin for sketchup work: nice roads with thickness.
As far as I know CADMAPPER uses OSM data like roads "width" for diferent types of highways. Can I use QGIS to extract/generate roads with boundaries (outlines) like on this screenshot (for extracting to shapefile), not just centerlines-network-system?



OSM road data extract will be simple polyline but QGIS can style it as a thick line with border as needed....

@J.R, any thougths about how did they manage to get road outline geometry? They are using OSM opendata as well for their service. I really don't think that it's kinda like programming black magick.

In QGIS a simple way to get OSM data is to use the Quick OSM plugin (https://docs.3liz.org/QuickOSM/), you can also use the Geofabrik website (https://www.geofabrik.de/geofabrik/) that let you download free and/or paid OSM data

This is a symbol issue and not a geometry issue. How they symbolise the data to look like it does in the picture is unrelated to the geometry of the lines themselves. I believe you are thinking of representing the road network polylines as polygons, but the appropriate symbology can accomplish this without the additional processing.
The key to this is having separate attributes for each road type. The OSM road network includes these attributes. You can use the symbology to create a custom symbol for each road type. If you need to customise the attribute table to achieve this, you can do this manually or in a more automated fashion.
Expanding on this to include the helpful comment from @J.R above. The road network data required can be sourced using the Quick OSM plugin (docs.3liz.org/QuickOSM) or can be downloaded (both free and paid-for) at the Geofabrik website (geofabrik.de/geofabrik).

And just to add: the real width of the roads/lanes in OSM data is very rare, therefore I would imagine a kind of postprocessing is done. Either by style, either by buffer. On the other hand you will find ways drawn as areas in OSM as well, but that's usually done for squares, rest/service areas, some avenues, but again, not often.

@GrzegorzSapijaszko While the real width of road is rare there are always a classification (motorway, trunk, primary, secondary,...) that usually what is used to assign width (by giving an arbitrary width to each class)

@GrzegorzSapijaszko try to separate what a vector looks like and what it's physical geometry is. You can make it look like almost anything you like, with only some restrictions due to the geometry. It is very easy to make a polyline look like it has width/area even though it doesnt
